# FireBase Cannot find the firebase namespace;

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my web application which that implemented with `Laravel` i'm trying to avoid multiple login into web administrator, for this issue after create new project in `Firebase` i added this lines befor ` but i get error

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script>
    var session_id = "{!! (Session::getId())?Session::getId():'' !!}";
    var user_id = "{!! (Auth::user())?Auth::user()->id:'' !!}";

    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "x",
        authDomain: "x",
        databaseURL: "x",
        projectId: "x",
        storageBucket: "x",
        messagingSenderId: "x",
        appId: "x",
        measurementId: "x"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var database = firebase.database();

    if ({!! Auth::user() !!}) {
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user_id + '/session_id').set(session_id);
    }

    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user_id).on('value', function (snapshot2) {
        var v = snapshot2.val();

        if (v.session_id !== session_id) {

            console.log("Your account login from another device!!");

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = '/login';
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-analytics.js - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
    <anonymous> 
    <anonymous> firebase-analytics.js:1
    <anonymous> firebase-analytics.js:1
index.ts:79:11
    <anonymous> 
    <anonymous> firebase-analytics.js:1
    <anonymous> firebase-analytics.js:1

Uncaught Error: Cannot find the firebase namespace; be sure to include firebase-app.js before this library.

Uncaught Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Failed to register the Firebase Database Service (TypeError: firebase.INTERNAL.registerService is not a function)
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the value in the `databaseURL` property in the `firebaseConfig` does not point to an existing Firebase Realtime Database instance. You'll want to check that you copied the correct config, **and** that you went to the [database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/) and told it to create your database.

---

A second problem is that you include different major versions of the Firebase SDKs. Make sure these are all the same major version:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Also see [adding Firebase to your web app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn) in the documentation.